# How to set or change entity value before saving using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I would like to change entity value in case if it's for example NULL.
Unfortunately my code causes exception - it seems that id isn't set although 'translation' record is created in database and id is properly returned by getId method.

It's quite simple code, why it doesn't work?

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new Word();
    $form = $this->createForm(new WordType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);


    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //works fine - database record is created
        if($entity->getIdTranslation() == NULL){
            $translation = new Translation();
            $em->persist($translation);
            $em->flush();
            $entity->setIdTranslation($translation->getId());
        }


        $em->persist($entity);
        //throws exception - Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_translation' cannot be null  
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_word_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Edit: added part of my model and mappings info:

[image: part of model for overwiev]

Revelant Words mappings:

```
 /**
 * @var integer $id_language
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_language", type="integer")
 */
private $id_language;
/**
 *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language", inversedBy="words")
 *@ORM\JoinColumn (name="id_language", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $language;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Translation", inversedBy="words")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_translation", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $translation;
```

and Translations:

```
class Translation
 {

public function __construct() {
    $this->words = new ArrayCollection();
}
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function prePersist() {
    $this->created_date = new \DateTime();
}
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Word" ,mappedBy="translation")
 */
protected $words;
```

Also on side note:
 I'v created my db model using database modeling software (workbench) not by Symfony console tools and now I'm trying to setup Entities to reflect db model.
I'm not sure if its right approach - maybe my model is too complicated to work properly with Doctrine?

Comment: Can you show entity doctrine mappings ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lifecycle Callbacks**

Sometimes, you need to perform an action right before or after an **entity is inserted, updated, or deleted**. These types of actions are known as "**lifecycle**" callbacks, as they're callback methods that you need to execute during different stages of the lifecycle of an entity (e.g. the entity is inserted, updated, deleted, etc).

Lifecycle callbacks *should be simple methods that are concerned with internally transforming data in the entity* (e.g. setting a created/updated field, generating a slug value)

If you need to do some heavier lifting - like perform logging or send an email - you should register an external **class as an event listener** or subscriber and give it access to whatever resources you need. For more information, see How to Register [a Event Listeners and Subscribers.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

Comment: The Doctrine documentation on this can be found at :http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events .
Symfony docs are located at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html . Dont forget if your using annotions in php you need to add 
`/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */`
to your doc header.

Answer (score 1):

A better place for this is the `Word` class's constructor:

```
class Word
{
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Translation", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $translation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translation = new Translation;
    }
}
```

BTW, you don't need to persist the translations ID manually because it's handled by Doctrine.

```php
$word = new Word;

$em->persist($word);
$em->flush();

$translation = $word->getTranslation();
$translationId = $translation->getId();
```

Comment: Thanks for response and useful informations, but in my scenario I want to be able to create new Translation if its not already given  - ie id_translation is null, I tried using prePersist approach but ended up with error telling about em not available in entity scope. Well maybe I should read more docs instead of trying to learn framework by creating sample project.